# Azure Service Principal rotation (Graph API permission to managed identity)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

My end goal is to be able to rotate SPN secrets and add
the new secret to Keyvault. I thought of using Azure
Automation account runbooks to do it. However, I think
the managed identity of the automation account must
have the graph API permission to readwrite applications
(owned or all) Currently I am not sure if there is any way
to provide graph API permission to Managed Identity's
Enterprise Application via portal, I have the powershell
script to do it. Is there any other way to achieve the spn
rotation without graph API admin consent? Will giving
Azure AD built in role of application administrator do
the same job as Graph API permission or I am missing
something. Is there a better way to manage SPN creation
and secret rotation?

I tried logging in via runbook using managed identity but it doesn't have enough permissions to create or manage app registrations

Comment: can't you use a managed identity as well rather than a SPN ?

Comment: The SPNs are used as service connections for Azure DevOps. Changing that to self hosted agents managed identity will be a big task for now

Comment: fair enough. i don't think you can get away from assigning owner permission over the SPN to manage. you said you have a powershell script, is there any issue with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the managed identity's service principal the "Application Administrator" directory role (possible through the portal), and granting it the Microsoft Graph app role "Application.ReadWrite.All" (possible only through API/PowerShell) both result in the managed identity having almost identical privileges.

Keep in mind that both of these approaches are *extremely* high privilege, as they allow effectively "taking over" an app identity which might be granted privileged access. I recommend you treat both almost like you're granting the managed identity (and everyone who is in a position to authenticate using that managed identity) as if they were Global Administrator and had full access to all your M365 and Azure environments.

Instead, you might want to consider a couple alternatives:

- Assign the managed identity's service principal the "Application Administrator" directory role at the scope of the individual target application and service principals (not tenant-wide).
- Grant the managed identity's service principal the Microsoft Graph app role (application permission) *Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy* (e.g. [using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell#grant-access-to-microsoft-graph)), and make it owner of each of the target application and service principals